# Hyperleadger Fabric Instllation

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have Just moved from Ethereum to Hyperleadger Fabric and struck on the installation of fabric on windows 10 system. Followed all the steps in the doc [Getting Started](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/getting_started.html) but could not make it work on Windows 10, get struck on the command ./byfn.sh -m up. But was able to get it trough on a Ubuntu system.

Is there a method to install Hyperledger without Docker, as we have all the files at [fabric](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) ?

All the installation and environment setup, network setup or chaincode setup is via docker, any docs to do things from scratch ?

Comment: You can find some references here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070380/does-hyperledger-fabric-need-docker

Answer (score 0):

For a start use the following official link:`https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/fabric`

To directly jump into building your first network setup,`http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html`. For better result change version to 1.0 which is stable.
[image]